# How to remove one occurrence of a char in a string?

Tags: java

I wrote this code a few days ago

```
String removeAll(char c, String s) {

  String to_return = "";

  while(true) {
      if (s.equals(""))
        return to_return;

      // at this point s is not ""
      char c2 = s.charAt(0);
      if (c2 != c)
      {
        to_return += c2;
      }

      s = s.substring(1);
  }

  return to_return; // won't be reached
}

print(removeAll('o',"hello"));
```

Pretty much.. removes ALL the 'o' from the string.. BUT I out did myself, I was only supposed to remove one occurence of the char..

Anyone be able to help me with removing just one?

Comment: What is `print` supposed to be?

Comment: if there are multiple occurrence of the char in string, what should be removed?

Comment: Not to answer your question, but you should use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` for `to_return` (then, return `to_return.toString()`), otherwise your method will take quadratic time.

Comment: you want implement to remove the first occurrence of the char in given string ?

Answer (score 3):

An efficient method is to use a StringBuilder:

```
public static String removeFirst(char ch, String s) {
    int charPos = s.indexOf(ch);
    if (charPos < 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return new StringBuilder(s).deleteCharAt(charPos).toString();
}
```

Alternatively, concatenate the substring before the character and the substring after it:

```
public static String removeFirst(char ch, String s) {
    int charPos = s.indexOf(ch);
    if (charPos < 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, charPos) + s.substring(charPos + 1, s.length());
}
```

Or use the built-in String method replaceFirst():

```
public static String removeFirst(char ch, String s) {
    return s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("" + ch), "");
}
```

Notes:

- The `replaceFirst()` method uses a regular expression to match, so you should make sure you properly quote the character to avoid problems with special characters that are meaningful in regular expressions (e.g. `$`).
- Instead of `"" + ch` you could use `String.valueOf(ch)` but I find that more of a mouthful (though more "correct"). If you're worried about making this code fast, I'd avoid using `replaceFirst()` as it's very slow - behind the scenes it compiles your expressions into regular expression patterns each time it's run.
- You ought to name your method `removeFirst()` and not `removeAll()`, otherwise it's going to be very confusing to the next developer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `StringBuilder` which has `deleteCharAt` method to remove the char at particular index.

```
     String inputString = "hello";
    char c = 'e';
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
    sb.deleteCharAt(inputString.indexOf(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the first `char` ocurring in the `String`. Added a `boolean` to know if a `char` was already removed or not.

```
String removeAll(char c, String s) {

        boolean removed = false;

        String to_return = "";

        while(true) {
            if (s.equals(""))
                return to_return;

            // at this point s is not ""
            char c2 = s.charAt(0);
            if (c2 != c)
            {
                to_return += c2;
            }
            else
            {
                if(! removed)
                    removed = true;
                else
                    to_return += c2;
            }

            s = s.substring(1);
        }

    }
```

Output example for `removeAll('o',"oh, hello")`:

```
h, hello
```